# Spring Boot with Embedded Tomcat: Session not persisting through restart

Tags: spring-mvc, session, tomcat, spring-boot

The research I've done on this seems to indicate that this should happen automatically.  Some writings suggest that it is required to place `server.session.persistent=true` inside src/main/resources/application.properties.  I have done this and I believe sessions are still not persisting.

Some background:  Using Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat and Spring MVC + Thymeleaf.  The user "logs in" to my application using their google account.  Once they are authenticated by Google, my application gives them a unique identifier which is stored as a property inside the user's HttpSession.  This property is of type Integer.  I do have an H2 database hooked up to this application but from what I've read I should be able to solve this problem without having to worry about storing sessions in the database.

When I launch the application using gradle (bootRun), I receive a cookie with my JSESSIONID as expected and I login with my user.  The user can navigate to different pages in my Spring MVC application and they are still 'logged in' by virtue of the session attribute being set on the server side.  When I stop the process in my IDE (to my knowledge this is not the same as terminating it) and restart it, then visit my application again in the web browser, I am immediately issued a different JSESSIONID.

It seems to me that the immediate problem is that my session is not being remembered between server restarts.  I have seen some writings that hint at implementing my own 'session store' or something like that, but I assume that first it is necessary for the server to understand that this is the same session.

I'd be happy to provide more information that would help, thanks everyone who took the time to read this.

Final Notes:
I am not using Spring Session or Spring Security, at this point I don't anticipate needing to for this project.

This is a "prototype" application for my own personal use, so feel free to warn about design issues but it is not my intention to make it bulletproof from a security perspective.